# use variable inside function within function

Tags: php, function, class

i am trying to access `$managers` variable in `change` function.

```
public function ManagerPerDay() {
        $query = $this->mysqli()->query('SELECT
                                            manager,
                                            count(manager) AS count
                                        FROM
                                            DATA
                                        GROUP BY
                                            manager
                                        ORDER BY
                                            count DESC');
        $data = $query->fetch_all();

        $managers = $this->GetManagers();

        function Change($n)
        {
            $name = $managers[array_search($n[0], array_column($managers, 'id'))]['name'];
            $n[0] = $name;
            return $n;
        }

        $data = array_map('Change', $data);

        array_unshift($data, ['Manager', 'Per Day']);
        return $data;
    }
```

i have tried global $managers; in change function but it also does not work.

Comment: You can declare a function inside a function, but calling the outside function more than once will result in a redeclaration error for the inner function.  Better to use a closure here.

Comment: The reason your global declaration didn't work is because you'd need to declare $managers global within both functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) which allows you to add your parameters

```
function Change(&$n, $key, $managers)
        {
            $name = $managers[array_search($n[0], array_column($managers, 'id'))]['name'];
            $n[0] = $name;            
        }

        array_walk($data, 'Change', $managers);
```

Comment: @BARNI, if the answer was useful you may click the checkmark ✔ to accept it (this is how you reward people for their effort).

Comment: Sorry, was not online (checked ✔).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `use` keyword to pass that variable to the function. Something like this for example:

```
$data = array_map(function($n) use ($manager) {
    $name = $managers[array_search($n[0], array_column($managers, 'id'))]['name'];
    $n[0] = $name;
    return $n;
}, $data);
```